# Edit varbinary fields as varchar and then insert back as varbinary

Tags: sql, cursor, sql-update, varchar, varbinary

I need to take a varbinary(max) field and do a replace on the contents of that field as varchar(max), then I need to insert the changes back into the column as varbinary(max). I thought the best way to do this was using cursors. Here is what I have, but I am not sure how to update back to varbinary(max)...Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
declare @content_id int
declare @content varchar(max)

declare cur cursor for 
    select d.content_id, CAST(d.content as varchar(max)) as content from item as a
        join assignment as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
        join attachment as c on c.att_id = b.att_id
        join digitalassetcontent as d on d.content_key = c.content_key
            where c.att_type like 'text%';
Open cur

fetch next from cur into @content_id,@content
while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

begin
update digitalassetcontent
SET content = replace(content, '<STYLE>H1{font-weight:bold}H1{font-size: 14pt}OL</STYLE><H1>Product Description</H1><P>', '') 
where content_id = @content_id

fetch next from cur into @content_id,@content
End

close cur
deallocate cur
```